# How do I get a datetime object with offset from a Django ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

I need to capture a date string with users UTC offset. Django returns the error 'Enter a valid date/time' every time. The browser is sending a string like this '2019-07-24 12:45:00 -05:00'

I am using bootstrap_datepicker_plus, (https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus/) to render a DateTimePickerInput field in my Django(2.1) ModelForm. I am trying to get a DateTime value that includes a UTF offset. I can see the date coming through in my is_invalid() method of my view when I print form.data['release_at']. It comes through like this '2019-07-24 12:45:00 -05:00'. Why doesn't' Django like this date format?

ModelForm

```
class Meta:
    model = Post

    today = datetime.datetime.today() 
    tomorrow =pytz.utc.localize(today + datetime.timedelta(1))
    twoWeeks = today + datetime.timedelta(14)
    dateFmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
    datejsFmt = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z'

    fields = ['title', 'body', 'release_at']

    widgets = {
       'release_at': DateTimePickerInput(
               format = dateFmt,
               options={
               "format": datejsFmt, 
               'minDate': datetime.datetime.strftime(tomorrow, dateFmt),
               'maxDate': datetime.datetime.strftime(twoWeeks, dateFmt),
               })
        }
```

Settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS += ('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z',)
```

CreateView

```
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(form.data['release_at'])
        print(parse_datetime(form.data['release_at']))
```

output from CreateView

2019-07-24 12:30:00 -05:00
None

Comment: `DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS += ('%Y-%m-/%Y %H:%M:%S %z',)` misses the hypen before `%z`.

Comment: Also there is a `/%Y` in third place where there should be `%d` according to your example.

Comment: I caught the /%Y problem and fixed that. The - is part of the UTC offset, is it not? Adding it to the format string did not help.

Comment: What is your `LANGUAGE_CODE` setting value ? Also, what default language does your browser use ? Also did you remove the extra `/`? If so please edit your post.

Comment: My current LANGUAGE_CODE setting is ['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M', '%m/%d/%y', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z']